# How to make Google crawler see asynchronously loaded data

Tags: axios, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, google-crawlers, nuxtjs3

I'm currently building a blog using Nuxt 3 + Axios to load data from a headless CMS.

Until the content is loaded, I display a content placeholder and replace it once the Axios request is done.

The request is launched on the Mounted hook.

I tried to preview the page using Google Search Console but the article content is not present on the page.

I'm worried that it will not improve the SEO rank of the website and I would like to know if I need to load the data on Server side and have it directly when the page is loaded and how.

Comment: You should probably start to use `useFetch` or `useAsyncData` hooks and have your content generated on the server yeah, otherwise you will not get any benefits overall. Make sure that your app is also using SSR or SSG, and is not only an SPA.

Comment: Quick and simple way to double check that is to disable JS for testing purposes or to check the source code.

Comment: @kissu I tried to use useFetch but half my requests are in client and half in server, any idea how it would be possible ? I make them in setup.

Comment: Hm, you're not the only one with this issue apparently. Do you have a [repro]? Also, did you checked the discussions/issues there? https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions